# Solving First-Order Difference Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations

How much of the theory and technique taught at the start of an ODE course for solving first-order differential equations applies to solving first-order difference equations?

Is there a way to separate variables to solve a difference equation in cases where it would work for a differential equation?  For example, the differential equation $y' = \frac{3}{n + 1} y$ is separable.  Can $y[n + 1] = \frac{3}{n + 1} y[n]$ analogously be separated to reach a solution?

Do inverting the product rule using integrating factors, variation of parameters, homogeneous tricks, any of the ODE techniques related to exactness or differential forms, etc., have analogies for first-order difference equations, and if so, how are they applied?

Comment: I don't know of any such analogies, but you might want to look in Jordan's "Calculus of Finite Differences". Once you get used to the language (which is somewhat antiquated at times) it's an extremely comprehensive reference.